# Overriding a function in base class php

Tags: php

In an instance such as the following which is called?

---

This is our base class

```
<?php

class baseService 
{
  public function __construct() 
  {
    //constructor code
  }

  public function handleRawRequest($_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST) 
  {
    $this->handleRequest($url, $method, $parameters, $requestBody, $accept);
  }

  public function handleRequest($url, $method, $parameters, $requestBody, $accept) 
  {
    switch($method) 
    {
      case 'GET':
        $this->performGet($url, $parameters, $requestBody, $accept);
        break;
      default:
        $this->notImplementedResponse();
    }
  }

  public function performGet($url, $parameters, $requestBody, $accept) 
  {
    $this->methodNotAllowedResponse();
  }

  protected function methodNotAllowedResponse() 
  {
    // out put some sort of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
  }
}
?>
```

We extend this to a specific service to provide certain functionality

```
<?php    
    require "baseService.php";

class betterService extends baseService 
{
  public function __construct() 
  {
    // stuff
  }

  public function performGet($url, $parameters, $requestBody, $accept) 
  {
    //do some stuff
  }
}
?>
```

Then using a another php file we create a better service and send some requests to it like such:

```
<?php
    require "NameRestService.php";

$service = new NameRestService();
$service->handleRawRequest($_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST);
?>
```

Do we get to do some stuff or is the method not allowed message returned?
If it is indeed the second how can it be changed to do stuff?

Comment: You can use another flag parameter to identify which to overload.

Comment: oh?
Could you please explain how to go about doing so?

Comment: It will call the child method of BetterService and "do some stuff". You don't have to change anything, if that's what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace $this by self:: to execute the method from the calling class.

```
self::performGet(...
```

Comment: `$this->performGet()` calls the overriden method in the child `betterService`, no need for using `self::performGet()`.